# Next.js UseRouter not mounted

Tags: next.js, navigation, slug

I'm using Next.JS and i want to pass a slug to my site.

This is the code that i have:

```
'use client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { slug } = router.query;

    return (
        <p>Post: {slug}</p>
    )
}
```

However, upon doing this i receive an error:
NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

I am not finding much documentation on this, the only thing it leads to is a next-router-mock package. However, i don't know if this is the right thing for me.

I tried using next/navigation, but i can't seem to find anything related to a router. I am not sure what the alternative for it is. I am new to next.js, so i am sorry if this question seems obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i figured it out.

UseParams was what i was looking for
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params

Thanks for the reply :^)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the router from `'next/router'` with the new app router. You have to use the router from `'next/navigation'` (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) in this case. However that router doesn't have a `query` property, for that you need to use the new `usePathname` hook (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname) Your code should be something like:

```
'use client';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Home() {
    const pathname = usePathname();

    return (
        <p>Post: {pathname}</p>
    )
}
```

Comment: I understand that using next/navigation is required now, but i don't know how to use slugs with this method. 

is there no way for a next.js route be customers\view\[slug] for example?
and then getting the [slug] value in the view page so that i can display the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in params property now:

```
export default function Home({params}) {
  const { slug } = params
}
```