# next.js dynamic route || TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'router.query' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I create in next.js dynamic page by id.

Structure:
app/shop/[id]/page.tsx

content:

```
"use client"

....
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
..
..
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';


    export default function Shop({ children, sections = [] }) {
      const [shopData, setShopData] = useState(null);
      const router = useRouter();
    
      // Get the id from the route
      const { id } = router.query;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            if (id) {
              const response = await fetch(`/api/shop/${id}`);
        
              if (response.ok) {
                const result = await response.json();
                setShopData(result.shop);
              } else {
                console.error('Failed to fetch shop:', response.statusText);
              }
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching shop:', error);
          }
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, [id]);
```

I try pass page ID to API but everytime I get

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'router.query' as it is undefined.

Source
app\shop\[id]\page.tsx (25:10) @ id

  23 | 
  24 | // Get the id from the route
> 25 | const { id } = router.query;
```

also I try router.query.id fallowing to documentation next.js but also the same issue.

Also I try change from  `import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';`  to  `import { useRouter } from 'next/route';`  but then I get `useRouter is not mounted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
`import { useRouter } from "next/router";`

or if it does not work then you can check [Next.js UseRouter not mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239346/next-js-userouter-not-mounted)

Comment: yes, but then I get Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

Source
app\shop\[id]\page.tsx (22:26) @ useRouter

  20 | export default function Shop({ children, sections = [] }) {
  21 | const [shopData, setShopData] = useState(null);
> 22 | const router = useRouter();

Comment: from documentation they said should be use  next/navigation

Comment: This can also happen when you try to use the useRouter hook from next/router inside the app directory, as the App Router's useRouter from next/navigation has different behavior to the useRouter hook in pages.

Comment: please check this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239346/next-js-userouter-not-mounted

Comment: yes thats it. Working now with useParams. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I helped